# PHP unlink not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, unlink

codeigniter folder structure

```
application
system
user_guide
uploads
```

Code:

```
unlink('http://sale.coupsoft.com/uploads/'.$checkbox[$i]['Image']);
```

I want to remove file from uploads folder but I am an unable to delete file by using HTTP.How can I remove file? my coding is correct but I am using HTTP so this displaying error. I am weak in English. so please apologize me if I made any Grammatical or spelling mistakes.

Comment: You have to provide relative path in unlink().

Comment: can you explain me how to write?

Comment: For example if you have windows system you have to write path like c://xampp/htdocs/projectfolder/uploads/filename instead of http://localhost/projectfolder/uploads/filename

Answer (score 4):

you can not use image full path please add image full path /var/www/html/projectfolder/uploads/filename.
See Below Codeigniter Example:

```
<?php 
  $url = FCPATH . 'uploads/filename';
 if (unlink($url)) {
  echo "File Successfully deleted."; 
 } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlink does not work like that, its works on relative path, try it like this :

```
unlink('./uploads/'.$checkbox[$i]['Image']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlink does not working like this . You should pass relative path of your file rather than absolute path. 
Also For any file three step neccessary as:

```
file_exists
realpath
is_writable
```

After this unlink for delete file

```
unlink('./uploads/'.$checkbox[$i]['Image']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it's working for mine:

```
$url = FCPATH.'uploads/'.$checkbox[$i]['Image'];
if (unlink($url)) {
  echo "Deleted!"; 
}
```